# Modifying external configuration section using Web.config transformation

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, web-config, web-config-transform

Let's suppose I have a configuration section on an external file, with the following element:

```
<my-config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <file value="XXX" />
    <!-- ... -->
</my-config>
```

Now, I want `value` to be `YYY` when the solution is built in **Release**.

Im using [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) for the web application deployment so I have the full benefits of [Web.config Transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx)

I know how to achieve this if the configuration section is **embedded** in the `Web.config`:

```
<my-config>
   <file value="YYY" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" />
</my-config>
```

But how can I accomplish the same thing when the section is on an external file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SlowCheetah](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/). It's a handy tool that enables you to transform your app.config or any other XML file based on the build configuration. You can use just nuget package or install [Visual Studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5).